# Moving LMDB from Laptop to SBC?

Tags: monerod, linux, lmdb, windows

I have a synced Database on my Laptop running W10, but I want run monerod on my Odroid C1 running debian linux. Is it possible to move the database from the Laptop to the SBC

Answer (score 3):

<s>It **might** work</s>. Edit: As per hyc's comment, it will work fine.

You can safely try as it would properly trigger an error.

[Here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/is-the-monero-blockchain-database-portable-between-32-and-64-bit-architectures) is a detailled answer.

Comment: It will work fine. No "might" about it.