# How to move/copy monero wallet and data

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui

Is it possible to copy or move the entire monero wallet and all associated/needed data/config files?  Can we basically backup monero wallet as it is setup with blockchain, configs, keys, wallets, all and everything necessary to zip move unzip and use.  Reviewed similar issues but none directly address a formal backup recovery situation which differs from importing mnemonic/keys or blockchain individually to recreate wallets and data. Hope i have explained the similarity and differences to resources linked below.

reviewed:
How do I move the blockchain (data.mdb) to a different directory during (or after) the initial sync without losing the progress?
[How do I move the blockchain (data.mdb) to a different directory during (or after) the initial sync without losing the progress?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/7225/4173)

Moving LMDB from Laptop to SBC?
[Moving LMDB from Laptop to SBC?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/4577/4173)

speed up initial blockchain sync
https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync

Answer (score 1):

While the daemon is not running, you can copy the contents of the ~/.bitmonero directory. This contains the blockchain and a few other files. This is all the data the daemon needs.

For the wallets, three files are created. If you name the wallet X, you'll get files named X, X.keys, X.address.txt. You can copy those as well to backup wallet data.

The blockchain is portable except between machines of different endianness. The wallet keys (the "X.keys" above) are portable everywhere. I'm not sure about the wallet cache data (the "X" above).